# Play Framework CacheApi injection return NullPointeerException in singletone

Tags: java, caching, dependency-injection, playframework, singleton

I have a play framework application. I am trying to get access to the cache through static method. I decided to wrap the cache into singleton but I get NullPointerException when try to access to the cache variable in class CacheSingleton. How the problem can be solve? Thanks.

```
import javax.inject.*;
import play.cache.*;

@Singleton
public final class CacheSingleton {
    @Inject CacheApi cache;
    private static volatile CacheSingleton instance = null;


    private CacheSingleton() {
    }

    public static CacheSingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized(CacheSingleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new CacheSingleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}

public class CustomLabels {
    public static String get() {
        CacheSingleton tmp = CacheSingleton.getInstance();
        try
        {
            tmp.cache.set("key", "value");
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not use static injection.**

It's not possible "in general":
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22068572/1118419

Play use Guice for DI and Guice could do a static injection, but this ability is highly not recommended:

https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/Injections#static-injections

The correct way to [use `CacheApi` in Play](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaCache):

```
import play.cache.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Application extends Controller {

    private CacheApi cache;

    @Inject
    public Application(CacheApi cache) {
        this.cache = cache;
    }

    // ...
}
```