# JPA @EJB injection does not work and give NullPointerException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I've a war file which runs on a wildfly application server.

When I do a SOAP request, a servor log error occurs saying that my EJB session is null. Here's my code :

**ColisDAO.java**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ColisDao {

    public static final String SELECT_ALL_COLIS = "select * from Colis;";

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="bdd_colis")
    private EntityManager em;

    public ColisDao() {

    }

    public void creer(Colis colis) {
        ...
    }

    public void remove(Colis colis) {
        ...
    }
}
```

**RecoveryImpl.java**

```
public class RecoveryImpl  {
    @EJB
    private static ColisDao colisDao;

    public static void fillDataBase() throws IOException {
         ...
         some code 
         ...
         colisDao.creer(c); //here's my error NullPointer
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="bdd_colis" transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>java:/bdd_colis</jta-data-source>
        <class>data.Colis</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

I dont really understand where I've wrong, maybe I have to create ejb file and use `InitialContext.lookup()` function but I don't really know how to use it in my context.

Any suggestions ?

## UPDATE

Finally found the solution : 
Here's my new RecoveryImpl class :

**RecoveryImpl.java**

```
@EJB(name="ejb/colisDao", beanInterface=ColisDao.class)
public class RecoveryImpl  {

    public static void fillDataBase() throws IOException {
        try {         
            colisDao = (ColisDao) new InitialContext().lookup("ejb/colisDao");
        }
        colisDao.creer(c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to inject a CDI Bean into a static variable in Java EE 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225179/is-it-possible-to-inject-a-cdi-bean-into-a-static-variable-in-java-ee-6)

Comment: `colisDao` is static - static fields can't be injected with CDI

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer, Indeed I saw others topics but available solutions still did not work. I will try now your suggestion and come back to you soon.

Comment: So I just did your suggestion my server keeps the same error

Comment: If removing the static variable and method didn't fix it, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RecoveryImpl class is not a bean, so ColisDao bean won't be injected. Only if class is a bean(specified using annotations like @Stateless @LocalBean), beans get injected.

If class isn't bean and still you want to bean in that class,(hereRecoveryImpl class): Way to access it is using 
*lookup method of Context*

Comment: Indeed, finally used the second solution, I updated my post for more precisions. Thanks for your answer :)