# Arquillian @BeforeClass injected EntityManager null

Tags: jpa, junit, jboss-arquillian

I'd like to persist some data using an instance of an `EntityManager` using Arquillian. To do so I'd like it to be done once before all the tests, so I tried using `@BeforeClass` like so

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        // create deployment
    }

    @PersistenceContext
    static EntityManager em;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        em.persist(someObject);
    }

}
```

Using this approach however the EntityManager is null. I can get this to work with `@Before` but obviously this runs before every test method which I don't want.

Comment: I think that the problem is that BeforeClass is executed first at client side (which em is null) and then to container side. Can you try to do something like if em != null and execute and see if it works?

Comment: You can't inject into static fields. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225179/is-it-possible-to-inject-a-cdi-bean-into-a-static-variable-in-java-ee-6