# How to Inject a managed bean(non-static) into static method?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, cdi, static-methods

I am using Java CDI for bean lifecycle.

```
@Named
public class ManagedBeanClass{
    ...
    public ManagedProfile getManagedProfile(){
       return new ManagedProfile();//logic will goes here
    }
}
```

For Example

```
public class sample1{
      @Inject private ManagedBeanClass managedBeanClass;
      ...
      public static boolean methodExample() throws Exception{
           ManagedProfile managedProfile = managedBeanClass.getManagedProfile();
           ....
      }

}
```

Try to Inject(@Inject) Managed bean into Static method ,it shows compaliaton error

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field
>   managedBeanClass

Getting stuck with Context DI and Static Object lifecycle.
Help me resolve this thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not going to work. Why does the `methodExample()` method need to be static?

Comment: The instance level `managedBeanClass` field won't even be _accessible_ from the `static` method.  One option is to make `sample1` managed, and set the `static` field from the constructor of that (and then potentially destroy the managed instance if you don't need it anymore).  Another is to have the `managedBeanClass` set itself as the static field on the `sample1` class.  But as @SeverityOne has pointed out, both leave the question as whether the method _should_ be `static`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your example code has nothing to do with CDI; You are trying to access a non-static field (`managedBeanClass`) from a static method. This is not possible in Java (neither with nor without CDI).

Also, static methods almost always point to a design problem (*). Having static methods like that make your program harder to test and harder to change / maintain. Try to come up with a design that does not need static methods at all...

So, the short answer is: Don't.

But if your really **must** have a static method here, you can use constructor injection and set a **static** field from the constructor. **But beware**: This is potentially dangerous, because every new instance would set the field again (which could cause race conditions and unexpected behaviour).

(See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22068572/10363398)

(*) With a few exceptions, like the methods in the Math class. But those are very small, pure functions that have no side-effects.

Comment: *"Also, static methods almost always point to a design problem (*)."* ... I guess the guy who wrote *"prefer static factory methods to constructors"* got it all wrong.

Comment: Thanks david. How the context of the bean changes by using below mentioned 
 //@Inject private ManagedBeanClass managedBeanClass;  // @Inject private static ManagedBeanClass managedBeanClass;

Comment: @scottb no, static factory methods would be one exception, I actually like them; It's the only chance you have in Java to give a "constructor" a "name. That's why I wrote "almost". Unfortunately you can't use them with DI containters like CDI - or, at least I don't know how to do that.