# Why is @Inject giving null in my java application?

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I have following `Parent` class as `main` in my java application.

```
@Named
class Parent {
    
    @Inject
    private static FactoryA factoryA;

    private Map<String, String> myMap;

    public static void main {

        // Here factoryA is coming as null.
        factoryA.getChild(myMap)
    }

}
```

`FactoryA` implementation

```
@Named
public class FactoryA {

    @Inject
    @Named("childA")
    private Child childA;

    @Inject
    @Named("childB")
    private Child childB;
    
    public Child getChild(Map<String, String> myMap) {
        if (myMap.get("PARAM").equals("CHILDA")) {
            return childA;
        } else {
            return childB;
        }
    }
}
```

Why in the main class am I getting `factoryA` as `null` ?

Comment: you need to start your DI framework in your `main`. You don't do this, so nothing gets injected. Which DI framework are you using?

Comment: I have not implemented any DI framework in my java application. Can you help me with an examples?

Comment: Annotations are not magic. Something has to process them.

Comment: Welcome: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19225179/592355  (`@Inject` + `static` is problematic/awkward)

Comment: Ok, I will use usual Factory design without injecting, using constructors.

Comment: or to put the cart before horse: (Why) It has to be static?!:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to inject a CDI Bean into a static variable in Java EE 6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19225179/is-it-possible-to-inject-a-cdi-bean-into-a-static-variable-in-java-ee-6)